# Fetch the Application Name of a Program using cmd

Tags: cmd

I'd like to fetch the Program Name of an Application using cmd but I don't know how should I do it, for example I have this application with a filename of **Rufus v2.14.exe** and I want to get its Program Name which is **Rufus** only using this 
`wmic datafile where name='c:\\users\\username\\desktop\\rufus v2.14.exe' get name`
 batch file code, but the result is not that what I think of, it gives me this result 
`c:\users\username\desktop\rufus.exe  2.14` 
which is still the same name. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for several `FileVersionInfo` fields.

In Powershell:

```
Get-Command .\rufus-2.18p.exe|Format-List


Name            : rufus-2.18p.exe
CommandType     : Application
Definition      : C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\rufus-2.18p.exe
Extension       : .exe
Path            : C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\rufus-2.18p.exe
FileVersionInfo : File:             C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\rufus-2.18p.exe
                  InternalName:     Rufus
                  OriginalFilename: rufus.exe
                  FileVersion:      2.18.1213
                  FileDescription:  Rufus
                  Product:          Rufus
                  ProductVersion:   2.18.1213
                  Debug:            False
                  Patched:          False
                  PreRelease:       False
                  PrivateBuild:     False
                  SpecialBuild:     False
                  Language:         Sprachneutral
```

Comment: Can I use still use that with cmd?

Comment: You can wrap it like this `powershell -nop -c "Get-Command .\rufus-2.18p.exe|Format-List"`